# Cannot find the option of LDAP Authentication in Review Board

Tags: review-board

Cannot find the option of LDAP Authentication after upgrading to 3.0.2. Currently, there are only two options understand the Authentication Method in the user Admin page. They are Standard registration and Legacy Authentication Module.

System: RedHat

May I ask how to solve the problem? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is Djblets also need to be upgrade. You may find more information in /apache2/logs/error_log